# jsp: How can I protect a jsp page with a password?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, password-protection

I would like to protect a jsp page with a password that needs to be typed.

In apache i can add a password file to .htaccess but I don't know how to do that in apache tomcat.

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, you basically want to put HTTP BASIC authentication on the particular JSP page? Here's a step by step:

1. First you need to declare the desired rolename, username and password in `/conf/tomcat-users.xml`.

   ```
   <tomcat-users>
       <role rolename="yourrole"/>
       <user username="yourname" password="yourpass" roles="yourrole" />
   </tomcat-users>
   ```

   (you can append as many `<role>` and `<user>` entries as you want; if there are already existing entries, then you just add them inside `<tomcat-users>`).
2. Then you need to declare the desired security constraint on the `url-pattern` of the JSP file along with a login config of `BASIC` (which stands for HTTP BASIC authentication).

   ```
   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>A JSP page</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/page.jsp</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
           <role-name>yourrole</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   <login-config>
       <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   </login-config>
   ```

   The `/page.jsp` should match the context-relative URL of the JSP page. The `yourrole` should be the same as the rolename as definied in `/conf/tomcat-users.xml`.

Restart the server, open the JSP page in the browser and use `yourname` and `yourpass` to login.

Comment: To which file do I add the security constraint listed in 2.?

Comment: @Will: the JSP page which you'd like to protect with a password, exactly like as this question is all about :)

Comment: @Will: yes, just specify the URL pattern you'd like to protect. The matching is done on basis of the URL pattern, not on basis of the resource type.

Comment: Just to verify, #2 is added to the web.xml of the application, not the web.xml in the Tomcat conf folder, correct?  (It didn't seem clear to me.)

Comment: There is a comment above that makes it sound like it goes in the `jsp` file; it doesn't go there.  I put it in the `web.xml` file of the project.  I'm not sure if it can also go in the tomcat `web.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Complete information is here [Apache Tomcat 6 Realm Configuration HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html).

The easiest way is to use the [MemoryRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#MemoryRealm) to define the user (name, password and role) in tomcat-users.xml and define the resources you want to protect in your application web.xml.